# min_samples_split must be at least 2 or in (0, 1], got 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I have defined a binary classifier as bellows: I call it with 'gbc' method (Gradient Boosting Classifier), and I get the error `min_samples_split must be at least 2 or in (0, 1], got 1` in the last line. featuresClasses is a data frame, and featureLabels are list of features.

```
Binary_classifier(method, featureLabels, featuresClasses):

    membershipIds = list(set(featuresClasses['membershipId']))
    n_membershipIds = len(membershipIds)

    index_rand = np.random.permutation(n_membershipIds)
    test_size = int(0.3 * n_membershipIds)

    membershipIds_test = list(itemgetter(*index_rand[:test_size])(membershipIds))
    membershipIds_train = list(itemgetter(*index_rand[test_size+1:])(membershipIds))

    data_test = featuresClasses[featuresClasses['membershipId'].isin(membershipIds_test)]
    data_train = featuresClasses[featuresClasses['membershipId'].isin(membershipIds_train)]

    data_test = data_test[data_test['standing'].isin([0, 1])]
    data_train = data_train[data_train['standing'].isin([0, 1])]

    X_test = data_test[featureLabels].as_matrix()
    y_test = data_test['standing'].values.astype(int)

    X_train = data_train[featureLabels].as_matrix()
    y_train = data_train['standing'].values.astype(int)

    # -------------------------- Run classifier
    print 'Binary classification by', method

    if method == 'svm':
        classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
        y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)

    elif method == 'gbc':
        params = {'n_estimators': 200, 'max_depth': 3, 'min_samples_split': 1, 'learning_rate': 0.1, 'loss': 'deviance'}

        classifier = GradientBoostingClassifier(**params)
        y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [GradientBoostingClassifier documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html):

> min_samples_split : int, float, optional (default=2)
>
> ```
> The minimum number of samples required to split an internal node:
>
>     If int, then consider min_samples_split as the minimum number.
>     If float, then min_samples_split is a percentage and ceil(min_samples_split * n_samples) 
>                are the minimum number of samples for each split.
> ```

You, in your code have specified `'min_samples_split': 1`. This is not a valid case. The minimum int value for it is 2. 
If you wanted to input 1 as float (that means 1*number of features) (i.e you want to take all your features into `min_samples_split`), then specify as `'min_samples_split': 1.0`. When specified as 1, it is taken as an int, and hence the error occurs.

This is a discrepancy on the error showing as (0,1] instead of (0.0, 1.0], which is causing the confusion. This has also been asked on github issues of the scikit-learn and has been implemented in next release:

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8041